# Кирилица в Get запросе curl

Tags: php, curl, get, кириллица

У меня есть скрипт который отлично работает с базой, но проблема возникает когда пытаюсь отправить запрос содержащий кирилицу через php, когда как запрос через открытие url адреса в браузера работает отлично.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, array('ru_RU.utf8', 'ru_UA.utf8')); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, array('ru_RU.utf8', 'ru_UA.utf8')); 

function call($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($data) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

$query  .= $GLOBALS['api']."/tables/?transform=1&filter[]=Name,eq,".$rus_name;
$decode = json_decode(call('GET', $query), true);
```

Если делаю `echo $query` и просто вызываю этот запрос в браузере все работает,
если же в запросе есть кирилица и делаю запрос через call function то ничего не возвращается

`$query = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', 'русский текст');`
и `$query = urlencode($url);` НЕ помогли...

Пожалуйста помогите, пол дня провозился

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlencode` необходимо использовать только для части URL, то есть, если применить urlencode целиком к адресу, будет закодировано, все, например:

```
 echo urlencode("http://exmaple.com?et=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ");
 // вывод - http%3A%2F%2Fexmaple.com%3Fet%3D%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95
```

а правильно будет:

```
 echo "http://exmaple.com?et=".urlencode("ЗНАЧЕНИЕ");
 // вывод - http://exmaple.com?et=%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95
```

То есть в вашем случае:

```
 $query .= $GLOBALS['api'] . "/tables/?transform=1&filter[]=Name,eq," . urlencode($rus_name);
```

Comment: Пробовал не помогло(

Comment: Как оказалось ошибка была у меня в скрипте, два раза конвертировал результат. Спасибо твой ответ подтолкнул на мысль